# WPF: Auto shrink object in the grid when another is increasing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am building a chat app for windows and the main app screen is built from two different views. First one is ListBox for messages and another one is RichTextBox for text input.

RichTextBox have property of MaxHeight and it can expand to it when the user puts allot of text into the box. But the problem occurs when the text box gets expanded and it overlaps over the ListBox view.

I dont know how can I force the ListBox to shrink accordingly to the TextBox height when it expands

Example:

[image]
Part of the XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="0,55,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
    <ListBox 
        global:ListBoxEx.AutoScrollToEnd="True" 
        ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="Scroll_ScrollChanged"  
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
        BorderThickness="0"  
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="0,0,0,61" 
        Padding="5,0,5,0" x:Name="Scroll" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    </ListBox>

        <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White">
                <Grid Margin="20,0,20,0">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0 2 0 0" Padding="0,0,0,5" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button Grid.Column="0" Height="40" FontSize="30" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="40"/>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <Border MinHeight="35" MaxHeight="200"  Background="White" BorderThickness="20" BorderBrush="Black" >
                                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" IsItemsHost="False">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <toolkit:RichTextBox   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,33,0">
                                                <toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                                                    <local:InputFormatter />
                                                </toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                                            </toolkit:RichTextBox>
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                                <Button FontSize="20" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                 </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Height="40" Width="40"  Margin="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />    
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                </Grid>
           </Grid>          
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you post your XAML (or a cut down section showing the list box and text box) to give a little more context please?

Comment: Please post your XAML code and screenshot

Comment: I have added example of functionality and some of my XAML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try playing with the `RowDefinition` of the grid.
`Height="*"` means that it will fill the remaining space, disregarding its content.
`Height="Auto"` means that it will expand according to its content.

Here is a simple example that you may adapt to your code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph FontSize="24">aaa</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```